# Rewrite urls using Apache PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a number of urls that are stored in a database, and thus instead of adding a rewrite rule in .htaccess for every url, I am using the following code in htaccess to give the control to PHP code through the following ReWrite rule in Apache:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

A url mentioned in the database, has a corresponding original url. Though, the tricky situation comes when I have to serve the content of the url fetched from DB by the corresponding original url for which the ReWrite rules are written in .htaccess. One solution is to implement the same rewrite rules for the url fetched from DB in PHP as written in Apache  for the original url, however, the number of such original urls is huge.

Thus would be glad to know about a solution if possible which can make execution flow through the ReWrite rules mentioned in Apache after the processing inside PHP is complete.

Comment: Don't need the dot `RewriteRule ^.*$ /rewriteurl.php  [L]`. I guess you have to use `/rewriteurl.php` to look for the original URL based on the request. As it is, have to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP to get the request. Or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` if you pass the URI-path as a query in the rule.

Comment: @faa, I am serving the additional rewrite rules via rewriteurl.php(PHP Code) and am not trying to rewrite /rewriteurl.php url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the main httpd.conf you could use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) written in PHP.

Other than that, there is no way you can give control from PHP back to Apache so Apache can process it further, not in the same request anyway. You could do a 30x rewrite from PHP to let Apache work on the next request.

Comment: the other possibility is to create an output filter in Apache, will still look into ReWriteMap, if it works in this situation

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. it really stands out from all other alternatives that I have explored..

Answer (score 0):

Basic rewriting, rather create an apache rule to redirect all 404 errors to a php file, which will be your url handler,  using the requested url do a lookup in your list  of urls in your database, return the original url to your handler, from there either do a redirect or fetch the page contents server-side/ajax the page/iframe whichever you perfer, if the requested url is not in your list display your custom 404 page, this kills two birds.

Setting up a 404 page:
http://www.404-error-page.com/404-create-a-custom-404-error-page.shtml

Comment: I understand the technique of using 404 thing, however, it will ultimately lead to fetching the content from another curl request from server side which will break in situations where Session variables are used

Comment: use an iframe? in the 404 handler with the src as the correct url, maintains both. overhead is the secondary http get for the iframe, which personally i would steer clear of.

Comment: iframe is a bad solution, when thinking about SEO.